# why firmware will be missing? Doesn't it come with the product?

Tags: driver, archlinux, firmware

I'm tring to install arch linux on my mac mini from a usb stick. But I'm stuck at the beginning:

```
[    9.138816] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[    9.138900] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[    9.138959] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[    9.139003] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode15.fw failed with error -2
[    9.139349] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Dri … cefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

I google around about firmware and drivers. My understanding is that firmware is some software comes with the product in read-only memory(some where on the product has this firmware burned in)

Why this error message tells me to download the correct firmware?
Can firmware be changed ?
Even if the firmware doesn't match the driver, shouldn't it be to download the driver for the firmware??

I'm totally confused, in my mind, the firmware is already there on the product, if anything wrong, it should be problem of driver.

Can someone help me clarify ?

Comment: Off-topic here, should be on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and you need to describe much more your hardware

Answer (score 2):

Yes, firmware can be changed and it is not always in ROM. They are often used by kernel modules (at module installation time).

On Debian Linux I install packages like `firmware-linux-nonfree` and many others, e.g. `firmware-realtek` (for my desktop). You need to find the firmware package relevant for your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

**Firmware** is the low level SW that handles HW components programming/functionality. While **Drivers** are the bridge b/w HW component and OS where OS can communicate with HW. Drivers expose some functional APIs that OS can perform using HW.

In your case, since your Linux has a newer version of driver that's not able to match Firmware version, it complains to install newer firmware.

BTW, Firmware need not be hard burned on HW, it can be re-programmed depending on hardware. Most of them support EEPROM/Flash and for SW, some devices run whole linux kernels now a days.